# I have an audio player that starts on my home screen

Tags: swift2, xcode7

Whenever I go back to my home screen it replays the music over the already playing music. I tried making an if statements that 'obviously' doesn't work (because I barely know any swift!). Here is my home screen code:

```
    var myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    let myFilePathString =
    NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("16 March of the Resistance",     ofType: "m4a")

    if let myFilePathString = myFilePathString
    {
        let myFilePathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myFilePathString)

        do{
            try myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: myFilePathURL)

            myAudioPlayer.play()
        }catch
        {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

How can I stop it from playing on top of itself?

Here is a picture of my storyboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0rlD.png)

The music player is on StartScreen, but when I click the back button, it starts another music player over the current one.

I need code which says

is myAudioPlayer playing?

if yes do not play song again

else play "16 March of the resistance"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z2iq.png)

Comment: upload your images from your computer, that way the links wont break in future

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you are already playing. You can do this by [the `playing` property of the `AVAudioPlayer` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/playing).

Guard your `viewDidLoad` with say:

```
if !myAudioPlayer.playing
```

Note that I don't know any Swift.

Comment: I know, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "my home screen", is it the device or your main VC? Why are you overriding viewDidLoad()? A previous player could never be playing in the viewDidLoad() call, unless for a leak which is what's needing fixing.

Otherwise, you just need to declare your player as an optional, rather than creating it in the declaration. As for the replaying or overlapping, just check if you player exists, although you wouldnt do this in your viewDidLoad(). ViewDidLoad() is called when the view of the VC is created and the view loaded, which doesn't relate to your lifecycle of the audio.

Depending on your requirements, you might want to create the player somewhere else that is plays throughout the app, rather than restarting when visiting that VC. Otherwise the code below will avoid the duplication. The problem was this `var myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()` which would duplicate players and one wasn't being released.

```
var myAudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

func viewDidLoad() {

    // this should never be needed with correct player setup
    if let player = myAudioPlayer where player.playing {
        return
    }

    if let pathString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("16 March of the Resistance", ofType: "m4a")
    {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathString)
        do{
            try myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            myAudioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

So there is no need to make the VC do this. Create a Class of e.g. AudioController, which could even be a singleton. Initialise it in your AppDelegate and trigger this player setup code after initialisation. Your view controllers dont need to know about the audio controller. IF e.g. you do want to modify the volume from a setting page, you just access the singleton object and set its volume.

This way you keep all your audio controller code nicely separated. Dont just think of functionality, think of overall software architecture, with objects having clear responsibilities. Keep your ViewControllers light, they shouldnt be doing much processing.

Take a look at this [Singletons](https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/) , its really easy to setup a singleton in Swift nowadays.

```
class AudioController {

    static let sharedInstance = AudioController()

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    let kVolumeKey = "VolumeKey"
    let kHasSavedInitialVolumeKey = "HasSavedInitialVolumeKey"

    var volume: Float = 0.5

    func setup() {
        self.loadVolume()
        self.setupPlayer()
    }

    func updatePlayerVolume(volume: Float) {
        self.audioPlayer?.volume = volume
        self.volume = volume
        self.saveVolume()
    }

    func saveVolume() {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: kHasSavedInitialVolumeKey)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(self.volume, forKey: kVolumeKey)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    func loadVolume() {
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(kHasSavedInitialVolumeKey) {
            self.volume = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().floatForKey(kVolumeKey)
        }
    }

    func setupPlayer() {

        if let pathString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("16 March of the Resistance", ofType: "m4a")
        {
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathString)
            do{
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
                audioPlayer?.volume = self.volume
                audioPlayer?.play()
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, you can just setup the player from your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching

```
AudioController.sharedInstance.setupPlayer()
```

And then you can access the AudioController using `AudioController.sharedInstance.whatever` when you need to get or set. Also, you will need to implement the players delegate methods for handling the end of the song, possibly triggering a new song to play from a playlist(create a new object for this) or whatever. Your player delegate code is also nicely separated now.

Comment: what I mean by home screen is my first UIViewController. I'm overriding viewDidLoad() because some of my code requires it. Thanks. I will try you code...

Comment: I was following a youtube guide.

Comment: I think you need to explain the problem in more detail

Comment: My problem is that when I come out from my over VC and into the main VC it plays the music even if it is already playing which ends up with a whole overlapping mushy audio mess.

Comment: The music starts overlapping. I want to stop that, and make it so that when the track finishes it will start again

Comment: So, does the music stop playing when you leave the mainVC? Are you pushing the other VC using navigation controller? I need to know more about the lifecycle of the VCs and the playing audio.

Comment: The music continues playing everywhere in the app, but when you navigate the app and return to the home screen it starts playing again onto of the already playing music, so every time you return to the home screen in adds other layer of music resulting in a horrible jumble.

Comment: Sure. Do you want it to restart when the user loads the main VC again or should it continue uninterrupted? Are you just using the main VC to trigger the first loading of the song, with the intent of it playing continuously from the initial loading?

Comment: I would like it to play continuously with no interruptions the entire time the user uses the app.

Comment: I would also like it to have a volume connected to it, but it won't be on the main VC it will be in a separate connected VC called 'Settings'

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: Getting three errors. I will post an image at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Check the updated answer please. I havent tested the code, so some of the stuff you will have to figure out yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your storyboard it seems that when you click the Back button on the second ViewController you allocate another start screen and you push it on the screen.
It seems that you're using a `UINavigationController` if so when the back button is tapped you should call:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

If your showing it as a modal you should dismiss is like this:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```